# How do I get last hits when laning against two ranged heroes?

Tags: dota-2

One of the main times I struggle in Dota is when I am laning as a melee hero against ranged ones. Whenever I go forward to last hit they harass me a lot, and I lose a lot of health. Is there a good way to combat this?

Answer (score 15):

### Don't die

No matter what: don't die! Your survival is more crucial than your farm; it is more important that you stay in lane soaking XP than it is earning gold. I assume you are mostly referring to being an off-lane (Radiant top lane, Dire bottom lane).

### Last hit under tower

Ultimately, you want to keep away from the ranged heroes until you are more familiar with whoever who are playing and confident in your ability. It's best to stay close to your tower, and learn how much damage a tower does to each creep (6 hits for melee, 3 hits for ranged creeps) and learn exactly how to get last hits in between. Normally you'd want to hit each creep once (assuming your creeps aren't attacking it) and then wait for the tower to do 5 or 2 hits (depending whether the creep is melee or ranged) then get the last hit.

### Keep creeps at your tower

#### Body block

You can block your own creeps (body block: stand and move in front of your creeps path to slow them down) to keep creeps near your tower

#### Aggro enemy creeps

As [@Rishabh suggests](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/257697/130645), aggro the enemy creeps and let them follow you behind your own creeps.

#### Pull neutral camps

You can also pull the jungle creeps into the lane which will drag your creeps away. This is only advisable if the enemy has done the same, and your creeps are pushed up. This can also deny your enemy experience, and net you more CS (creep score) against those neutrals. Since your creeps will have less health or there will be fewer of them, the enemy creeps will make quicker work of them.

#### Which comes with its own risks

Be aware this comes with its own risks: your enemies may be able to push down the tower quicker which is not good news (whole team gets XP and gold, plus they gain map control). It's probably best to keep the enemies off your tower and forsake gold

### Items

Buy sustainability. Don't worry about getting a *Bracer* or *Null Talisman*, focus on getting a *Stout Shield*, *Tangos* (buy 8 if you want!), health pots, *Mangoes* and *Faerie Fires*. It is far better to stay in lane than it is to have to leave. Leaving lane forces you to lose XP and gives your enemies uncontested farm

### Kill neutral camps

It may be possible, if the enemy is pulling neutral camps into their lane and denying you the creeps, to kill the neutral camps instead. This will depend on who you are playing, but remember you don't want to lose too much health from doing this. It may be best to just stand within range of your creeps ([XP range is 1300 as of 6.79](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Experience) as @Joe points out in the comments)

### Don't. Die.

Your death is very detrimental. Understand that it is far more important to go without gold from creeps than it is to give a death to your enemies. Doing so subsequently leads to other actions:

- You lose out on any creeps that would've been safe to last hit, plus you miss out on all the XP. You lose gold from dying, and your enemies gain gold and XP
- the enemy carry that killed you gets gold for items and XP plus uncontested space to farm; or
- that support that killed you can now afford more wards or smoke <s>and an upgraded courier</s>* which now benefits the rest of their team. They gain experience and can now start roaming to other lanes for successful ganks

If you are going to take too much damage for the sake of a last hit: leave it! It will be very frustrating laning against a duo who deny all creeps etc, but dying is far far worse! You want to stay away from dying, so play safe even if you lose last hits!

### Practise!

Matchmaking sometimes takes 10 minutes to find a match. During this time, you *could* browse the internet, read guides or watch YouTube videos, **or** you could practise your last hits in the *Demo Hero* functionality (select Heroes, choose a Hero then select Demo Hero). Once your match is ready, it will alert you and you can select Accept to go into the match.

Note that as of the [spring cleaning patch](http://www.dota2.com/springcleaning/), a new training mode *Last Hit Practice* has been introduced for this exact purpose. This mode is better than the demo hero mode, as it focusses specifically on last hits (and denies).

* <sub>[The courier upgrades to the flying courier automatically as of 7.07](http://www.dota2.com/duelingfates/)</sub>

Comment: @JoeWallis thanks for the info, I will add to answer!

Comment: have quelling blade and 2 scout shield or 1 poor mans shield

Answer (score 2):

Ranged heroes almost always have an advantage over melee, except if they are in melee range, so for the most part you have to sort of deal with it and try not to die. A few things that can help though are trying to last hit only when they have just used an auto attack or ability, and won't be able to punish you for moving into their range. Also, if you are 1v1, consider moving into melee range and dueling with them and getting them low enough they have to back off. This is easier if you have a gap closer, but also risky if they are able to kite back, are crowd control you in some way. If you are 1v2 as melee vs double ranged, then you will probably just have to play safe until a teammate comes and helps.

Comment: Whoever downvoted could you please tell me why so that I might improve my answer?

Comment: Probably don't call them champions.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things you could try, to get last hits against 2 ranged heroes.

Stay behind the line of your creeps and right click the ranged hero and start walking towards your tower. This little trick will allow enemy creeps to follow you and you could have as many last hits as you want.

Comment: For this technique to work, you have to be within 500 range of the enemy creeps when you right click enemy hero. You can right click *any* enemy hero, even ones across the maps.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add up something.

### **Know your role and hero**

The other important thing is what your role in game and which lane you are standing. And it's important to know your hero advantages. For example, if you are **Bristleback** on the hardlane soloing against two range heroes you can go for stealing some creeps and getting experience or even outplay your enemies with juking in trees and using **Quil Spray**(don't sure about spelling). But there is other way if they are too strong for you or they come even with three heroes on you during first two minutes. You can go stack ancients or other camps. It's easy to farm them out later and get lost XP and gold.

### **PUSH THE LANE (sometimes)**

Here is another example of situation. Let it be safelane and you are farming against **Lich** and **Faceless Void**. In this kind of situation **Body block** is nice, but not enough against **Lich**. If your teammates don't want or just can't pool any camp(they maybe blocked), you will be struggle near enemy tower, but tower won't reach creeps(just because enemies can deny enough for this). Obviously, this position is not good for you - you can be harassed by **Lich** with **Frost Nova** and even can be ganked from river. So you should auto attack creeps and turn on your **Ring of Basilius**(if you have it), or even cast spells to push lane harder. The point is that your creeps will die under their tower and enemy creeps will go further from their tower. In such situation you obviously can't outzone enemies from XP but you can tilt their position a bit with such moves so that lane won't be stable.

### Help your team in hopeless situations or cooperate to clean the lane

In cases when you are already lost lane and they got some strong range hero that can easily kill you - **Lina, Necrophos, etc.**.